# Handle switch in a custom popup

Tags: android

This is the function of popup in the MainActivity, I have a switch in a custom popup.xml, if the switch is checked the app must exit. I've tried onCheckedChanged listeners but i didn't work out. How to handle Checks in the Switch.

```
 public void showExitPopup() {
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Objects.requireNonNull(myDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new 
    ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialog.show();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void showExitPopup() {

    Switch s1;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    s1 =(Switch) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.s1);
    s1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    Objects.requireNonNull(myDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialog.show();


}
```